# PowerShell to update webbinding SSL Certificate to a new imported certificate

Tags: windows, powershell, ssl-certificate

I am trying to automate the certificate renewal process. I am able to generate the certificate then import the certificate to the server and now just need to update the SSL certificate to the new certificate imported for a particular application(ex : ABC). No changes in other property like port number or anything else. Just need to point the SSL Certificate to the new one added for a particular application. I tried doing a lot of research but no luck. Please help

Comment: Have you looked at https://weblog.west-wind.com/posts/2016/Jun/23/Use-Powershell-to-bind-SSL-Certificates-to-an-IIS-Host-Header-Site?

Comment: yeah i saw this but in here they are creating a new site binding ... I just need to update a site binding to a new ssl certificate .... something like set-webbinding -propertname sslbinding "New Certificate Name" but could not find the syntax for this

Comment: "But this makes me think the "update" option is present in 1607 and newer." https://serverfault.com/questions/957404/when-is-netsh-exe-http-update-sslcert-available

Might be you don't have the correct version of `netsh`